# Octave: Loop over each element in a struct (And calculate on the values)

Tags: loops, for-loop, struct, octave

I want to create "n" vectors of "n" lengths, so I wrote the following:

```
  x = struct ();
  for i = 1:n
  x.(genvarname ("a", fieldnames (x))) = ones(1,i);
  endfor
```

No problem so far, it generates "n" variables with the "n" ones inside it, just as I want.

The problem is that now I want to calculate the 3 norms (1,2,inf) for each vector and then plot it.

```
 for [val, key] = x
    norm(val,1)
    norm(val,2)
    norm(val,inf)
 endfor
```

I can calculate the norms with this code, but I would like to sort it somehow. The best would be to create a new variable with the norms of a respective vector.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you just mean`norm1 = []; norm2 = []; norminf = []; for [val, key] = x;
norm1(end+1)=     norm(val,1);
norm2(end+1)=    norm(val,2);
norminf(end+1)=    norm(val,inf);
end` or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Rafael: Thank you for your interesting questions. To help people answering it would be nice if you could clarify it a bit. What do you exactly mean by "sort it somehow"? What is your goal?